# ScreenToWorldPoint with perspective cameras

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, unityscript, perspective

So I am having an odd problem just now. I wrote a small script that, when atatched to an object will cause it to face the mouse pointer. However, since I switched from an orthographic camera to a perspective camera, the script has ceased to work. I have added in some debug and it looks like the ScreenToWorldPoint is just returning the same value no matter where the mouse is. I suspect this has something to do with the mouse being a fundamentally 2D entity, but I am not sure how to solve the problem.

Any help is much appreciated! :)

```
 void Update () {
     Vector3 difference = camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
     //Debug.Log(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition));
     difference.Normalize();
     difference.Set (difference.x, difference.y, 0);


     transform.up = difference;
```

Answer (score 7):

[This is addressed in unity answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/331558/screentoworldpoint-not-working.html).

Unity Answers say, and I quote:

> ScreenToWorldPoint receives a Vector3 argument where x and y are the
>   screen coordinates, and z is the distance from the camera. Since
>   Input.mousePosition.z is always 0, what you're getting is the camera
>   position. The mouse position in the 2D screen corresponds to a line in
>   the 3D world passing through the camera center and the mouse pointer,
>   thus you must somehow select which point in this line you're
>   interested in - that's why you must pass the distance from the camera
>   in z. If you try something like this:
>
> ```
>  function Update() {
>    var mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
>    mousePos.z = 10; // select distance = 10 units from the camera
>    Debug.Log(camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos));
>  }
> ```
>
> you will get the world point at 10 units from the camera.

Please use google before posting a question. There is a high change that you will find your answer before posting here.